# $f$ is holomorphic in $B(z_0,r)\setminus\{z_0\}$ and does not except real values. Then $z_0$ is a removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

$f$ is holomorphic at $B(z_0,r)\setminus\{z_0\}$ and $f$ doesn't except real values - i.e $f(z)\notin\mathbb{R}$ for all $z\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $z_0$ is a removable singularity point ($f$ can be extended holomorphically in $z_0$).

Well I tried to use Riemann theorem, and show that $\exists 0<r'\le r$ such that $f$ is bounded in $B(z_0,r)$, but didn't succeed to do so. Formerly I solved a similar question which demand that $\Re(f)>0$ and then by defining $e^{-f(z)}$ which is holomorphic and bounded, which by taking $log$ holomorphic branch promises $f$ is holomorphic. Is there any manipulation or composition I may make to $f$, to get a similar results?

I also tried to assume that $f$ is not bounded, so in $B(z_0,r)$ one may find $z$ such that $|f(z)|$ is arbitrary big. However, is there any kind of intermediate value principle which assures that $f$ must "cross" the real line in case $|f(z)|$ is not bounded in $B(z_0,r)$?

Comment: Maybe you can just solve it in the same way you did the $\mathbb{R} > 0$ case just taking $if$ or $-if$. Notice that since the function doesn't take real values, the imaginary part of $f$ must be either positive or negative.

Comment: @astrobarrel Imaginary part must be positive or negative since $f$ preserves connectivity?

Comment: Just for the meanvaue theorem. Write $f$ as $f_1+if_2$. $f_2$ is continuous and real. So, assume for a moment that there are two points $z_0, \, z_1$ such that $f_2(z_0)<0<f_2(z_1)$. Take a continuous path $\gamma$ that goes from $z_0$ to $z_1$ and take the composition $f(\gamma)$. Now the meanvalue theorem takes care of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED: If $f$ has a pole at $z_0$, $1/f$ has a zero there, and by the Open Mapping Theorem $1/f$ would take all values in some interval near $0$.

If $f$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$, Picard says it can omit at most one value near $z_0$.

Removable is all that's left.

EDIT If you don't want to use the heavy artillery of Picard, note that if $f$ takes no real values, since $B(z_0,r)$ is connected the values it does take are either in the upper or lower half plane.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain why does $1/f$ takes all real values near zero by the open mapping theorem?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't as clear as I should have been.  I meant "all the  real values that are in some neighbourhood of $0$".  After removing the removable singularity of $1/f$ at $z_0$, the resulting non-constant analytic function maps a neighbourhood of $z_0$ to a neighbourhood of $0$, and any neighbourhood of $0$ contains some real interval $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$.

Comment: I should have understood that anyway, it was obviuous. Thanks for the clarification.